# Server connection Handler approach

Tags: android, sockets, handler

I am having my UI and I am starting my Socket connection to server in another thread. Problem is, I need to wait for server reply. When it arrives, I need to do specific funcions. I have found that Handler approach can be possible, but other sites are telling this is not true. What are your suggestions? Is Handler solution right and how to do it effectively? Any example?

Thanks

Comment: Handler will probably work but it's not a good approach since they are bound to the Activity life-cycle. A `Service` is not and should work better. It's just a bit tricky to get Service state displayed in your UI.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the AsyncTask?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Perform the network operation in the `doInBackground()`

Once it returns the `onPostExecute()` will be executed by the main thread which is able to update GUI etc.